# Finding BER, using FSK at GSM network

Tags: fsk

I would like to ask, cuz I don't know much from that, how we can find the BER at a GSM network (uplink & downlink separately of course), while we are using FSK modulation? I mean the equations precisely, cuz I searched the Internet and there's nothing clear. Most cases where about MFSK, QFSK etc., but not specific for FSK.

Comment: The standard expressions for binary FSK error probabilities are $$P_e = Q\left(\sqrt{\frac{E_b}{N_0}}\right), ~~\text{coherent demodulation}$$ and $$P_e = \frac{1}{2}e^{-E_b/N_0}, ~~\text{noncoherent demodulation}.$$ It is more complicated for $M$-ary FSK for $M > 2$. What exactly are you looking for?

Comment: It's a question for a project. Specific it says "Assuming we use modulation FSK, find the expected BER at uplink and downlink.". I'm also not sure what exactly does he mean. And don't except our teacher will explain us and there's nothing on the lesson's notes, so I don't know.

Comment: Correction: that should have been $\displaystyle \frac{1}{2}e^{-E_b/2N_0}$ for noncoherent demodulation.